# How can I make an ajustable table with minimum width of side cells and adjustable center cell

Tags: html, css

I need to make a table with 3 columns, side columns should have minimum width for showing content, central should be adjustable.

If table width will reach the width of container then text in central column should be truncated with ellipsis. But if content in center column is short, then column also should be short and right side column should be near content of central one.

There are my two different solution below, unfortunately both of them aren't perfect for me.

In this one behaviour of the 3rd row is incorrect - content of right side column isn't near content of central column:
https://jsfiddle.net/rqLsdvwd/4/

```css
.main {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 1%;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:600px">

   <div class="main">
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 1</div>
    <div class="box content">Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces</div>
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 1</div>
    <div class="box content">LongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpaces</div>
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 2</div>
  </div>
  
   
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 1</div>
    <div class="box content">Short info 2</div>
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 3 which should be near Short info 2</div>
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

In this one text without spaces isn't truncated:
https://jsfiddle.net/7gbux944/3/

```css
.main {
  width:600px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content::after {
    content: attr(title);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content::before {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div><span class="content" title="Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div><span class="content" title="LongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpacesLongInformationWithoutSpaces"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div><span class="content" title="Short info2"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="sidebar">Short info3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Could anyone suggest me something, please?

Comment: Neither of those look like tables...that's not a table layout.

Comment: @Paulie_D Why not? Table with only one row and very specific behavior. Any suggestion how can I describe it better or better how to implement it as I need?

Comment: If it's only one row it's not really a table is it?

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, from your answer I understood why you didn't like the word 'table' in my description. Actually in my case I will have only one row, several rows in my question I added just for showing different possible cases of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't realy a table just a combined series of independent rows.

However. Flexbox can do that

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="main">
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 1</div>
    <div class="box content">Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces Long Information with spaces</div>
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 1</div>
    <div class="box content">LongInformation</div>
    <div class="box sidebar">Short info 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, however, that this will NOT act a like a table; the widths of the various "cells" of each row are not related to the same "cell" in any other row.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try it.